# update data value in my database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, oledbcommand

i have a combobox populated with data :

```
Beef
Calamansi
Chicken
Egg
Fish
Fish_Sauce
Oil
Pork
Rice
Soy_Sauce
Vegetables
Vinegar
```

then if choose the Beef in my comboBox then press a button it will search my database Stocks_Name for Beef then in my textbox1 i will input an integer then add that to Total_Stocks equivalent to Beef data.
[image]

what commandtext should i use because i cant find a specific commandtext in the internet for my problem. i only know how to insert and select. thank you in advance :D

UPDATE:

it didn't add but instead it changed my data 100 to 1 it should be 101. here is my work: `

```
connection.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE Add_Stocks SET Total_Stocks=@QWE WHERE Stocks_Name=@STOCKS" , connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QWE", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STOCKS", comboBox1.Text);


cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
{
    MessageBox.Show("ADDED!");
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: UPDATE is what you need

Comment: yes i dont know what command text i should use for this operation. @DanielAbouChleih

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih UPDATE? can you provide me a short example for this.  i'm kindda new in using database in C#

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih sir i have a problem check my question for update.

Comment: Check your Set. It needs to be like this: `Total_Stocks=Total_Stocks+@QWE`. In your Set statement you set your Total_Stocks to @QWE which is your value of the textbox. BTW: You don't have to call me "sir" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the `UPDATE`-Statement which

> creates an update query that changes values in fields in a
>   specified table based on specified criteria.

Syntax:

```
UPDATE Your_Table_Name
SET Total_Stocks = Total_Stocks + @IncrementValue, 
WHERE Stocks_Name = 'Beef';
```

You'll need to add an Parameter to fill `@IncrementValue`

```
yourOleDBCommand.Parameters.Add("@IncrementValue", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(yourTextBox.Text);
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845036.aspx)

Comment: what is + 1? can i add here the integer from my textBox1?

Comment: Yes, you can add the value of your Textbox in there. Misread you question, thought you wanted to add 1 to Total_Stocks

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question their is simple query,

```
UPDATE Your_Table_Name 
SET Total_Stocks = Total_Stocks + @Int_Value_from_Textbox
WHERE Stock_Name = 'Beef'
```

where `@Int_Value_from_Textbox` is the parameter that u need to add to your command before executing.